# How to detect endianness from JNI code?

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I need to call the native function `int getSize(uint_64& out)` through JNI. There are obviously a few problems here that I intend to solve by passing `byte[]` to the JNI code, populating it with the value of `uint64_t &out`, and then creating a BigInteger out of the result. So, from Java I call `getSize(byte[] size)`, in JNI C code I pass a new uint64_t to `getSize(uint64_t& out)` and then copy the value from it back to the byte array, and finally I create a BigInteger out of this byte array. My question is how do I copy the `uint64_t` value into the byte array? I know that on the Java side the value has to be in big-endian order but how do I figure out what the byte order is of the `uint64_t`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The byte order of the `uint64_t` is the native byte order, of course, but you don't need to deal with endianness-ness at all here. Just return a `jlong` from your native method. It will arrive in big-endian order in the Java code, where the Java code can deal with it any way you like.

Comment: Wow! exactly that is the problem, we now need to ensure any Network-Packet IP is first converted to Host-Endian (Little-Endian in case of ARMv7 Android) cause Java converts it back to Big-Endian (Net-Endian) automatically.